# How to remove section in JSON after parsing a message in LogicApp

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Parsed Message
{
"date": "2022-02-04",
"customerID": 123,
"customerInfo": {
"id": 123,
"lastname": "Smith",
"firstname": "David",
"email": "testing@email.com",
},
"currency": "EUR"
}

I would like to remove the customerInfo section so the JSON looks like.
{
"date": "2022-02-04",
"customerID": 123,
"currency": "EUR"
}

How would one do this in the LogicApp. I tried remove property but could not get that working.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and removed customer info using remove property as below :

Firstly, I have initialized a variable as below:

[image]

Then I used compose operation as below:
In compose input: `removeProperty(variables('emo'),'customerInfo')`
[image]

Then i have set the variable with output of compose as below:
[image]

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Try to follow above process you will get to remove customerInfo as mine got.

Comment: If the message changes to the following.
{
  "messageId": "testmessage",
  "appointment": {
    "date": "2022-02-04",
    "customerID": 123,
    "customerInfo": {
      "id": 123,
      "lastname": "Smith",
      "firstname": "David",
      "email": "testing@email.com"
    },
    "currency": "EUR"
  },
   "eventId": 123,
}

when I use the removeproperty(emo[appointment],'customer info') I do not get the items outside of appointment.  Do I need to add them back.

Comment: I couldnt understand what you are asking, You need to still use removeProperty(variables('emo'),'customerInfo') to remove customer info (If this is not what you are asking, Open a new thread/Question and ask clearly).

Answer (score 0):

You just initialize new variable from that one and populate it

```
"Initialize_variable": {
      "type": "InitializeVariable",
      "inputs": {
         "variables": [ {
               "name": "sensitisedMessage",
               "type": "Object",
               "value":  { "date": @message['date'], "customerID": @message['customerID'], "currency": "@message['currency']" }
          } ]
      },
      "runAfter": {}
   }
```

I have not checked the format of the json in an actual logic app, but you get the idea